# Is it legit to have pages from the same domain in multiple rankings (domain crowding)?

Tags: google-search, ranking, search-results, google-ranking

I'm trying to optimize my site and notice that one of my competitors appears in all of the top 3 results same domain, different pages.

Is this normal or considered an abuse?

Does anyone have any comment about this can I should I report it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no violation of any sort for just being on multiple ranking in the first page.

Here's an example

### [image: http://cdn.searchenginejournal.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/image002.gif]

If there isn't any sort of spamming, backlink abuse or other blackhat practice, it's completely legit.

Here's some words from Matt Cutts that answer all your doubts.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxv-AvNPoh8

As he said, if a domain has very high quality pages about a topic, even if Google prefers diversity, they can show people resources from that domain in multiple rankings.

Comment: Straight from the horses mouth, very instructive, thank you!